# How to create a netCDF-4 file with a variable length variable from ncml?

Tags: java, dataset, netcdf, scientific-computing, ncml

I'm trying to write a netCDF-4 file with a variable length variable.

Ideally I'd have used the ncgen utility, but it does not support *ncml* input. Therefore, I'm using the netCDF-java lib 4.6.6. The following ncml without a variable length variable produces a workable netCDF-4 file:

```
java -Xmx1g -classpath ~/dump/netcdfAll-4.6.6.jar ucar.nc2.dataset.NetcdfDataset -in test.ncml -out test.nc4 -netcdf4
```

This is the corresponding ncml/xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://what.no">
  <group name="data">
    <dimension name="number_packets" length="6"/>
    <variable name="packet_time_utc" shape="number_packets" type="double">
    </variable>
  </group>
</netcdf>
```

If I'm adding another unlimited dimension to the ncml, failure occurs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://what.no">
  <group name="data">
    <dimension name="number_packets" length="6" isVariableLength="true" isShared="false"/>
    <variable name="packet_time_utc" shape="number_packets" type="double">
    </variable>
  </group>
</netcdf>
```

According to the ncml [schema](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2), the definition of the dimension is correct.
Error msg *NetCDF: Variable not found*:

```
NetcdfDatataset read from test-vlen.ncml write to test-Vlen.nc4 java.io.IOException: -49: NetCDF: Variable not found
        at ucar.nc2.jni.netcdf.Nc4Iosp.writeData(Nc4Iosp.java:2835)
        at ucar.nc2.jni.netcdf.Nc4Iosp.writeData(Nc4Iosp.java:2789)
        at ucar.nc2.NetcdfFileWriter.write(NetcdfFileWriter.java:954)
        at ucar.nc2.NetcdfFileWriter.write(NetcdfFileWriter.java:938)
        at ucar.nc2.FileWriter2.copyAll(FileWriter2.java:431)
        at ucar.nc2.FileWriter2.copyVarData(FileWriter2.java:384)
        at ucar.nc2.FileWriter2.write(FileWriter2.java:199)
        at ucar.nc2.dataset.NetcdfDataset.main(NetcdfDataset.java:1888)
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: -101: NetCDF: HDF error
        at ucar.nc2.jni.netcdf.Nc4Iosp.close(Nc4Iosp.java:289)
        at ucar.nc2.NetcdfFileWriter.abort(NetcdfFileWriter.java:1032)
        at ucar.nc2.FileWriter2.write(FileWriter2.java:207)
        at ucar.nc2.dataset.NetcdfDataset.main(NetcdfDataset.java:1888)
```

Specifying `length="*"`, as recommended [here](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/ncml/AnnotatedSchema4.html), results in a different NumberFormatException error.

I'm using the latest versions available:

- HDF 1.8.17
- netcdf C 4.4.0
- netCDF-java lib 4.6.6

The error is about the failure to find the variable (FileWrite wants to copy all variables). However, I'm stuck trying to find the origin of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced this with the netCDF-java lib *branch 5.0.0*; commit *0cc266d*, but the error is a little clearer:

With your second example:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions added to a group must be shared.
```

Upon removing `isShared="false"`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: variable length dimension cannot be shared or unlimited
```

It looks to me that there is no support just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not something we support in NetCDF-Java. I've made an issue about it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Unidata/thredds/issues/588).

Comment: thanks about that (I have not enough rep to upvote yet)